# REGEX trying hard but no result

Tags: java, regex, notepad++

I'm trying some regex with this kind of texts

```
    <div id="tabs-4">
            Se trata del medio por el que se transmite el mensaje y también hace referencia al código utilizado.
        </div>
        **</div>
<div id="pagina_3">**
        <div id="tabs-5">
            Entorno, situación en la que se establece la comunicación. De él depende la interpretación que la persona da al mensaje. También va a condicionar la comprensión del mismo.
        </div>
```

Text between *** is a misplaced string, and I'm trying to locate between divs with ID=tabs-X, but I'm always getting errors and timeouts

This part of my regex detects correctly the `div id=tabs` content

```
\<div id\=\"tabs\-[0-9]*\"\>(.*\s*)?\<\/div\>
```

but at the momtnt I try to add the second `</div>`, it crash

the correct text would be something like this:

```
    <div id="tabs-4">
                Se trata del medio por el que se transmite el mensaje y también hace referencia al código utilizado.
            </div>

            <div id="tabs-5">
                Entorno, situación en la que se establece la comunicación. De él depende la interpretación que la persona da al mensaje. También va a condicionar la comprensión del mismo.
            </div>
</div>
    <div id="pagina_3">
```

I'm trying too with notepad++ and happens the same, both solutions on java or notepad++ would be grateful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(\s*<div id="tabs-\d+">.+?)(<\/div>.<div id="pagina_\d+">)(\s*<div id="tabs-\d+">.+)
```

Ooops I'm late